# Bibliography not being printed

Tags: bibliographies

When I get my computer to run my code, it justs gives me a page with "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog." written on it despite the fact that I have a file called "Bibliography.bib" (I've checked the cases of the letters) in the same folder as my script. I don't get any question marks, I don't get any error messages, it just generates a pdf with the sentence and nothing else. Does anyone know how I should get the bibliography to print? Thanks.

Here's my script:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in, right=.5in]{geometry} %Defines margins

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography.}
\bibliography{Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Here's my bibliography file:

```
@book{harrington2003introduction,
  title={Introduction to Electromagnetic Engineering},
  author={Harrington, R.F.},
  isbn={9780486432410},
  lccn={2003055389},
  series={Dover Books on Electrical Engineering Series},
  year={2003},
  publisher={Dover Publications}
}

@book{boylestad1987introductory,
  title={Introductory Circuit Analysis},
  author={Boylestad, Robert L},
  year={1987},
  publisher={Merrill Publishing Company}
}

@book{consoliver1920automotive,
  title={Automotive Ignition Systems},
  author={Consoliver, L. and Mitchell, G.I. and University of Wisconsin. University Extension Division},
  lccn={20022307},
  series={Engineering education series},
  year={1920},
  publisher={McGraw-Hill}
}
```

Comment: BibTeX only adds works you actually cited to the bibliography. In the document there are no citations at all. If you add `\cite{harrington2003introduction}` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX you should see Harrington in the bibliography. If you want to add an entry to the bibliography without citing it, use `\nocite{<entrykey>}`. If you want to add all `.bib` entries to the bibliography without citing, use `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: @moewe I see. Thanks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments ...